# Best way of inserting 10 million records in a table from a select query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I wish to insert 10 million records into a table using a select query. This process is taking a very long time.. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can you post your SELECT query?

Comment: A lot of DBs use BCP, a bulk loading process...I believe Oracle has SQLLoader. -- "http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ"

Comment: what process? share [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The ubiqitous Don Burleson has a page dedicated to bulk inserts of data, it has links to the oracle documentation and other useful resources.

It can be found here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_data_load.htm

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comment mention bulk loaders.  If you have access, they can be very powerful.

In terms of pure SQL, you may find that you've got log file problems : If the transaction is cancelled, everything needs to roll back, and the log file holds everything necessary to deal with that.

To circumvent that, process your records in blocks.  Maybe 10,000 at a time, in a loop that iterates 1000 times.  The exact numbers to choose are a bit trial and error.  You want to do as much as you can in one go, without putting too much pressure on the log file.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I miss from DonBurlesons article is CTAS (create table as select). If your table is empty before the insert, this might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a "LOAD DATA INFILE" operation which replaces a table with a text file (essentially, a .csv file). I have only a half-million rows and it works great. Maybe Oracle has something similar.